# Ext-JS 4 with CakePHP vs Ext.direct

Tags: extjs, extjs4

I'm using Ext-JS 4 on client-side and for my server-side I'm using CakePHP. They are communicating with JSON.

I saw that Sencha Team created Ext.direct for communicating with server side (PHP, Ruby, .NET ect.).

So, can you tell me advantages and disadvantages of using Ext.direct over PHP framework like CakePHP or Zend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As usual, it brings you more organized and structurized code by giving an additional abstraction layer with no or very little performance loss. Use it over your framework. Or do not use. It's up to you.

Comment: When you can find a out-of-the-box implementation for your framework, take Ext.Direct, it's faster and plays nicly with ExtJS stores.   
For CakePHP there is Banchaproject.org to implement it, I'm not aware of a solution for Zend yet.

Answer (score 0):

Ext.Direct is a protocol, not an server-implementation! Ext.Direct has a lot of advantages over standard RESTful or "normal" js requests, because it specifically is written for Sencha Touch and ExtJS and so all models and proxies are already correctly configured and ready to go.

If you are using CakePHP there is a framework called Bancha which implements Ext.Direct into CakePHP. It also handles all the marshalling and data transformations to save you a ton of time.